# Why did Walt leave his gun on the couch when Jesse came to confront him?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

This question is about "End Times", the twelfth episode of the fourth season of *Breaking Bad*.

When Jesse learned that Brock had been poisoned, he came over to Walt's house to confront him. Walt opened the door holding a gun in his hand.

Even though Jesse was obviously mad at Walt, in a couple of minutes Walt left his gun on a couch and walked away, which allowed Jesse to hold Walt at gunpoint using Walt's gun.

Was that intentional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spoilers if you have not seen season 4 episode 13 (not sure if this should be in a spoiler block, remove if you wish):

> Yes. Walt wants Jesse to think that Gus poisoned Brock so Jesse will help him kill Gus. Now, for this to work, he needs Gus to have some plausible motivation. The one that makes the most sense is that Gus poisoned Brock so that Jesse would kill Walt out of anger. From Gus' point of view, this is ideal as Jesse was the one holding Gus back from killing Walt — If Jesse himself kills Walt then this is out of the question. Now, for this constructed fantasy to work, when Jesse comes to Walt's house, he must have the opportunity to kill Walt. Only then can Walt feign that he thinks that Jesse has come to kill him and put forward the argument that Gus manipulated Jesse into this position so that Walt would be killed. To this end, Walt left the gun on the couch on purpose.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. Thx!